# iOS Swift: How to change the Response from server to Specific Format?

Tags: ios, swift

I stored the data from server to NSArray, Here I want change the current format to new format. But I don't know how to change the current format to new.Please help me for make the format.
Here I have share the old format and new format as following.

This is old format received from Server.

```
{
{
“class” = “12”,
“section” = “A”,
“name” = “aathi”,
“mark” = “850”,
“school” = “ab matriculation school”,
“place” = “Chennai”
},
{
“class” = “12”,
“section” = “B”,
“name” = “ram”,
“mark” = “904”,
“school” = “ab matriculation school”,
“place” = “delhi”
},
{
“class” = “10”,
“section” = “C”,
“name” = “ashok”,
“mark” = “389”,
“school” = “psg hr sec school”,
“place” = “coimbatore”
},
{
“class” = “8”,
“section” = “B”,
“name” = “sundar”,
“mark” = “267”,
“school” = “govt hr sec school”,
“place” = “Madurai”
}
```

}

I want to change the new format like below.

```
{
{
“class” = “12”,
“section” = “A”,
“school” = “ab matriculation school”,
noncommondetails:{
        {
        “name” = “aathi”,
        “mark” = “850”,
        “place” = “Chennai”
        },
        {
        “name” = “ram”,
        “mark” = “904”,
        “place” = “delhi”
        }
    }
},
{
“class” = “10”,
“section” = “C”,
“school” = “psg hr sec school”,
noncommondetails:{
        {
        “name” = “ashok”,
        “mark” = “389”,
        “place” = “coimbatore”
        }
    },
},
{
“class” = “8”,
“section” = “B”,
“school” = “govt hr sec school”,
noncommondetails:{
        {
        “name” = “sundar”,
        “mark” = “267”,
        “place” = “Madurai”
        },
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to manage it from server side itself.

Comment: But they are not ready to do this...@Dev_Tandel

Comment: its gonna be heavy for loop for you then, comparing 5 elements and create this desire structure.

Comment: 100% this should done by server side. And its easy to handle from their side. When we changing this from app side, it will be heavy load for app & cause performance issues.

Comment: Yes bro, But they argue with me for this..@LalKrishna

Comment: Take a stand brother, it is un-ethical from their part.

Comment: If you are using Moya, then you can easily do with Moya's plugins

Comment: No there is no need to change from server. The change the server guys made is legit and it should be handle from the app side. I think there is nothing in the response which can cause  performance issues.

Comment: I have answered the question. Let me know if you are still confused.

Answer (score 1):

You must try https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper for json object mapping.

Answer (score 1):

The best design for what you are doing is to make models for your server response and then save those model objects in an array. That way you can change what you want.

**Model for your old format:**

```
struct Item {
    var aClass:String?
    var section:String?
    var name:String?
    var mark:String?
    var school:String?
    var place:String?
}
```

**Now models for your new updated server response:**

```
struct Item {
    var aClass:String?
    var section:String?
    var school:String?
    var nonCommonDetails : [NonCommenItem]?
}

struct NonCommenItem {
    var name:String?
    var mark:String?
    var place:String?
}
```

**And then you can use it like:**

```
let nonCommenItem1 = NonCommenItem(name: "aathi", mark: "850", place: "Chennai")
let nonCommenItem2 = NonCommenItem(name: "ram", mark: "904", place: "delhi")

let item1 = Item(aClass: "12", section: "B", school: "ab matriculation school", nonCommonDetails: [nonCommenItem1,nonCommenItem2])
```

I hope this solve your problem. If there is any confusion please ask. Good Luck :)

Comment: Why is everything declared as optional? Obviously the server sends always all keys.

Comment: But server can send null as well.

Comment: Can but does not.

Comment: If you are 100% sure then its okay you can declared it non optional.

Comment: @vadian Don not trust your server. Your app would crash if the type of the received data is mismatched. Just make your app more robust.